# Regex match similar pattern string but I need the last occurrence

Tags: regex

I have the following text

```
">UNWANTEDTEXT">APRODUCT</ProductCode>
```

I'm looking to build a regex statement with my desired result being the text

```
APRODUCT
```

The regex I have at the moment is this.

```
">(.*?)<\/ProductCode>
```

The problem I'm facing is that the same text pattern of **">** occurs at the start... I need a way of telling the regex to only look at the last occurrence of the "> then pull the value between it and **`</ProductCode>`**

Comment: You should probably post more of the text if there is more... Otherwise I'd just do something more like `'">UNWANTEDTEXT">APRODUCT</ProductCode>'.split("\">")['">UNWANTEDTEXT">APRODUCT</ProductCode>'.split("\">").length - 1].split("<")[0]` And also which implementation of regex... (A little about your stack)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to indicate which characters you want to match instead of any character, i.e. any character that's not a closing angle bracket:

```
([^>]*)<\/ProductCode>
```

If the string *can* contain a closing angle bracket *if* it's not preceded by a quotation mark, the solution gets a little hairier. Assuming your regex library supports zero-width assertions:

```
(?:">)?((?:(?!">).)*)<\/ProductCode>
```

Hope this helps!

I also want to add that if you're parsing SGML, you might consider using a library dedicated to that purpose instead of trying to cobble together your own parser based on regular expressions. That path is [fraught with peril](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1021515).

Comment: Looks good.. First and easiest solutions fits my scenario nicely. Thanks